# Dealing with long async operations and frequent events in Windows 8.1 apps

Tags: c#, event-handling, async-await

Consider the following:

```
  void event_handler(object sender, ...){
     DoSomething();
  }

  void DoSomething(){
     // change some page's state 
     // change some page's private members
     var someData = await LongOperation();
     // change some page's state 
     // change some page's private members
  }
```

Now, I would like the following behavior: if event_handler is triggered when the previous LongOperation() hasn't been completed yet, such a LongOperation() has to be cancelled.

What's the simplest and the preferred approaches to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancellation is best handled via a `CancellationToken`:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
async void event_handler()
{
  if (_cts != null)
    _cts.Cancel();
  _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  await DoSomethingAsync();
}

async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
  // change some page's state 
  // change some page's private members
  var someData = await LongOperationAsync(_cts.Token);
  // change some page's state 
  // change some page's private members
}
```

There are various optimizations, i.e., to reuse a previous `CancellationTokenSource` if the previous operation *wasn't* cancelled, etc. But this code illustrates the general principle.